# activeClassName not changing active link color

Tags: reactjs, navbar, jsx, next.js, reactstrap

I have simple navbar component made from reactstrap.

Here is my code:

```
<Container fluid>

          <div className='sample'>
            <Navbar color="light" bg="primary" light expand="md" >

              <Collapse isOpen={!collapsed} navbar>
                <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                  <NavItem>
                    <Link href="/dashboard">
                      <NavLink href="/dashboard" active={Router.pathname === "/dashboard"}>Dashboard</NavLink>
                    </Link>
                  </NavItem>              
                </Nav>
              </Collapse>
            </Navbar>
            {props.children}

          </div>


          <style jsx>{`

         .sample {
           background-color: red;
          // padding: 100px
         }

         .nav-link > ul > li > a.active {
          color:red;
        }

        .navbar-nav .nav-link.active{
          color:red;
        }

       `}</style>
        </Container>
```

I am trying to change active link / highlight color when link is active. 
I also tried using activeClassName="active" but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this shape

```
`<NavLink
  to="/dashboard"
active={Router.pathname === "/dashboard"}
  activeStyle={{
   what you wannt//
 fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "red"
  }}
>
  Dashboard
</NavLink>`
```

or add activeClassName="class_name"
as this shape

```
<NavLink  activeClassName="classname">
```